# Database & Server UML

Tags: java, database, client-server, uml, sequence-diagram

I'm designing a simple client-server system(JAVA) which stores some information on the server and I am currently creating sequence diagrams. My question is:

In UML should a'database' object be regarded as a  separate object from a'server' object?

Comment: UML is not like a Java compiler. Do what you think documents the best the system you're building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how much information you want to show to the person who is reading the diagram.

To a manager, you can show a diagram where the client stores in formation in the server, and leave all other details outside.

To an architect you probably want to show that the information is accepted by some kind of application which then stores the information in the database.

And to a programmer  you can show the specific classes which implement each one of the steps.

It is all up to you.